# Direct Sum (Linear Algebra) explanation

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

I just started a Matrix Theory course and I am having a hard time understanding some basic concepts.  I am trying to get my head in the game!

Can someone explain, in more elementary terms, what direct sum actually means?  The technical answer is not making sense to me.  Examples and non-examples?  Please break it down as much as possible.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forums! It would be great if you could edit you question with perhaps an example. Maybe you could state the 'technical' answer that you did not understand, and what you did not understand. Otherwise perhaps this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69835/understanding-direct-sum-of-matrices may help.

Answer (score 1):

First off, let V be a vector space ans U,W subspaces of V. Then we define the  sum of the subspaces to be $U+W=\{u+w: u \in U, w \in W\}$. Now, we say the sum is direct if $U \cap W = \{0\}$.

Per your request lets look at an example. Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ where can decompose $\mathbb{R}^2= \text{x-axis} \oplus \text{y-axis} \simeq \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$. If is clear that $\{x-axis\} + \{y-axis\}=\mathbb{R}^2$ and moreover the two subspaces merely intersect at the origin, making the sum direct. Furthermore, we can identify each as an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{R}$ and we have the result.

Comment: I am starting to get a better grasp.  Can you break down this particular definition of direct sum: Suppose U1...Um are subspaces of V.  The sum U1+...+Um is a direct sum if each element of U1+...+Um can be written in only one way as a sum u1+...+, where each uj is in Uj.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I was asking you to explain that particular definition if you could.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example where a direct sum has some physical meaning.

Consider two matrix-exponential distributions with vector-matrix representations:

$$<\bf{p}_1,\ \bf{B}_1,\ \bf{e}_1>$$

and

$$<\bf{p}_2,\ \bf{B}_2,\ \bf{e}_2>$$.

Then, the direct sum, $\bf{B}_k$, with vector reprentation 
$<\bf{p}_k,\ \bf{B}_k,\ \bf{e}_k>$, where

$$\bf{B}_k = \bf{B}_1 \otimes \bf{I}_2 + \bf{I}_1 \otimes \bf{B}_2 $$

$$\bf{p}_k = \bf{p}_1 \otimes \bf{p}_2$$

is the random variable that represents the minimum of $\bf{B}_1$ and $\bf{B}_2$. That is $<\bf{p}_k,\ \bf{B}_k,\ \bf{e}_k>$ is a representation of the minimum order statistic.

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

By definition a vector space $V$ is the direct sum of two subspaces $U$ and $V$, denoted by $V = U \oplus W$, if every element $v$ of $V$ can be written as a sum of elements of $U$ and $W$, i.e. $v = u + w$, for some $u \in U, w\in W$. In addition to this ability of being able to reproduce all of $V$ in terms of elemens of $U$ and $W$, we require $U \cap V = {0}$.

It can be shown that this definition is equivalent to being able to write $v = u + w$ such that the choice of $u$ and $w$ are unique. By uniqueness we can represent each $v$ as $(u, w)$ without loss of generality.

Entry-wise operations follow. Let $v_1 = u_1 + w_1$ and $v_2 = u_2 + w_2$, then $v_1 + v_2 = (u_1 + u_2) + (w_1 + w_2)$. By closure in their respective subspaces, $(u_1 + u_2) \in U$ and $(w_1 + w_2) \in W$. So that $v_1 + v_2$ which ca be written as $(u_1, w_1) + (u_2, w_2)$ equals $( u_1 + u_2, w_1 + w_2)$. Similarly, we can show $\lambda (u, w) = (\lambda u, \lambda w)$.

Note that in this representation, elements of $U$ and $W$ are written as $(u, 0)$ and $(0, w)$, respectively.

The canonical example is $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the $x$ and $y$ axes as subspaces: $\mathbb{R}^{2} = (\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}) \oplus (\{0\} \times \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thanks so much!